# Count occurrences of part key value in Dict (Swift)

Tags: swift, dictionary

Lets say I have a dict containing the following values and keys

```
let dict = ["Foo" : 1,
            "FooBar" : 2,
            "Bar" : 3,
            "BarBar" : 4,
            "FooFoo" : 5 ]
```

My question is :-

How would one count the occurrences of the KEY containing or partly containing the key string "Foo"

The result should be 3 ("Foo","FooBar","FooFoo" )

One direction I am looking at is using

```
print( dict.keys .contains("Foo"))
```

This of course returns true

```
print( dict.keys .contains("Fo"))
```

It will return a false value when in actual fact "Fo" occurs 3 times but only as a part key name.

Hoping that makes sense :F

So again how do I count the par key name occurrences in a given dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `filter` the keys and then count them

```
let arr = dict.keys.filter{ $0.contains("Fo") }
print(arr.count)
```

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way is this:

```
dict.filter{ $0.key.contains("Foo") }.count
```

We leave all the keys that conatins `"Foo"` in the dictionary and count the number of KVPs left!